# What is the best way to reduce json data size while sending to Kafka topic?

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka

In my application I need to send the json data to the cloud using the Kafka java producer. As I need to send data of size 10 KB (Byte form) very frequently, What is the best and optimize way to reduce the  data size, while sending to kafka topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing much you can do. I also wouldn't optimize the performance of data transfer channel. You can scale kafka instances horizontally if you have a performance issue. You wouldn't get much gain from compressing the format by 10%. You should always think how to improve the performance in 10x times, not at 10%. The only solutions that come to mind

- Json has a lot of duplicates, you can use other formats e.g. protobuf.
- in Json you can use non-formated versions w/o spaces and etc.
- Also kafka can store bytes, so you can gzip json and save it as steam of bytes, then ungzip.

Comment: Following are the limitation : 1) I cannot change the format from Json to any other.     2) I tried to zip and unzip, but there is a performance hit.

Comment: then you cannot do anything at all. Use short fields name in your models. Don't pass the information you can omit.

Comment: Update : I've tried out Apache Avro, It's reduced the data size (27 KB to 8 KB), when used along with Binary Encoder.